# AsyncLocal<T>-like functionality that is copied across awaits but not new tasks

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am creating a wrapper class for NLog. I would like to capture the logical execution flow across log entries. Traditionally, we could do this through the thread id; however, this becomes useless with asynchronous code, since another thread can pick up execution after an `await`. Therefore, I'm trying to introduce another field that is preserved across `await` calls.

`AsyncLocal<T>` meets this requirement. However, it also gets copied over when spawning new tasks through `Task.Run`, therefore reducing its usefulness since it gets shared across concurrent threads. Is there some functionality that preserves fields across `await` but not `Task.Run`? I don't mind what happens when joining concurrent tasks (e.g. `await Task.WhenAll`).

I'd like this to be something that can be done centrally through my wrapper class, not copied to all `Task.Run` calls.

```
var asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<string>();
asyncLocal.Value = "Test";

await Task.Yield();
Console.Write(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   // should be "Test"

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   // should be "null"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncLocal is supposed to be copied into forked flows, such as parallel child Tasks started with Task.Run or making multiple calls to async methods before awaiting them all at once, so both of those Console.WriteLine's should output "Test". It works as expected.

If you need the subtask to not run with the current execution context and its AsyncLocal values, then you can simply wrap it in a using block with ExecutionCOntext.SuppressFlow like this:

```
static AsyncLocal<string> asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<string>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async() => {
        asyncLocal.Value = "Test";
        await Task.Yield();
        Console.Write(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   //Writes "Test"

        Task task;
        using (var control = ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
        { 
            task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null"); //Writes "null"
            });
        }
        await task;
    }).Wait();
}
```

Do not await the task within the using block, or the continuation could pick up on a different thread, causing the disposal of the AsyncFlowControl object to throw an exception.

```
static AsyncLocal<string> asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<string>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async() => {
        asyncLocal.Value = "Test";
        await Task.Yield();
        Console.Write(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   //Writes "Test"

        using (var control = ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
        { 
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null"); //Writes "null"
            });
        } //Exception may be thrown here upon disposal
    }).Wait();
}
```

Do beware that this suppresses the entire execution context, not just AsyncLocal variables, so it's important to understand everything that flows with execution context and what may go missing.

Another option is to simply null out the AsyncLocal's value inside the subtask. Such changes propagate down into called methods and flows, but they don't propagate up the flow. So for example:

```
static AsyncLocal<string> asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<string>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async() => {

        asyncLocal.Value = "Test";

        await Task.Yield();
        Console.Write(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   //Writes "Test"

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            asyncLocal.Value = null;
            Console.WriteLine(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   //Writes "null"
        });

        Console.Write(asyncLocal.Value ?? "null");   //Writes "Test"

    }).Wait();
```